# Laravel : functions in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm asking myself if i'm doing things in the right way. Here is my concern :

I have my User Model like this

```
class User extends Model {

public function activities()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Activity');
}

....

public function getTotalDistanceTraveled() {
    return Step::join('activities', 'activity_id', '=', 'activities.id')->where('activities.user_id', $this->id)->sum('steps.km');
}
```

Is it the right place to put function like getTotalDistanceTraveled() in the User Model ? Or it should be in the Controller which generate the View ? Or do I have to create a UserRepository ?

Thanks for your recommandations

Comment: It should be in another model and then make a relations to them

Comment: There are also an Activity model and a Step model which are related together. What I want is to get the total distance of all steps travelled by a user. In which model do you recommand to put this function ?

Comment: I see. Put that in your controller now to get the returned object

Comment: As you return steps I would put it into the Step model. Would confuse me to get a instance of `Step` in the User model.

Comment: I would suggest you create a repository and do your math there. Then you can keep your models clean and concise.  The controller is not a place for this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it depends on the size of the app. If it's a simple app that is going to take very little maintenance and basic Eloquent queries then sure keep them in the model - what's the point in troubling yourself over a small app?

If your app is going to be constantly maintained and large in size then I would result to a Repository design, that way you keep everything organised, maintenance is easier and anybody else working on the project with yourself can find their way around relatively easier.

Personally on a large app I like to have repositories but split my more advanced, complex queries into a dedicated class for each query and remove them from the repository. This for me makes maintaining easier.

Controller wise, I personally prefer to keep my controllers 'skinny'. But a simple Eloquent query isn't going to hurt anything for example:

```
public function view($id) 
{
    return view('view-user')->with('user', User::find($id))
}
```

It ultimately depends on the scope of your app.